# i want keyboard not to show up at all when i touch my text input-React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want keyboard not to show up at all when i touch my text input.If i use 'Keyboard.dismiss' i loose the focus on my text input i am using custom keyboard which itself is part of my screen so i don't want any keyboard to show up at all without loosing the focus on my text input, any solution please.I have tried using libraries but facing same problems again and again what should i do. Here the code i Am using

```
<TextInput onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss}>
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Have you tried: `Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => Keyboard.dismiss());`. I didn't test it and it may flash the keyboard before dismissing it, but as a suggestion may be worth of trying.

Answer (score 24):

Use `<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false} />` 
It will hide the keyboard when you focus on the text input.

Comment: showSoftInputOnFocus does not work on ios https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#showsoftinputonfocus

Comment: @Angel S. Moreno - currently showSoftInputOnFocus is available for both Android and iOS.
I didn't put this in a comment since my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Comment: This is perfect solution, instead of using TouchableOpacity and other hacks.

Answer (score 9):

ReactNative TextInput has `showSoftInputOnFocus` prop, which is due to docs should hide keyboard. But seems like it doesn't work.

I found this solution, works for me:

```
 <>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggleVisible}>
  <View>
    <View pointerEvents="none">
      <Input
        value={String(value)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
<DateTimePicker
  isVisible={this.state.visible}
  onConfirm={onChange}
  onCancel={this.toggleVisible}
/>
```

Comment: `showSoftInputOnFocus` is for Android only - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#showsoftinputonfocus

Comment: The above code works better when you use TouchableOpacity than TouchableWithoutFeedback.

Answer (score -1):

Correct way is to encapsulate View with keyboard is calling Keyboard.dismiss()
you should use TouchableWithoutFeedback so that on clicking it should disable 
the keyboard

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <TextInput keyboardType='numeric'/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Try this may be it can solve the problem

Comment: thanks but the whole purpose is not to loose my focus from the text box so i can use my keyboard